# SDP Offer WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, nest, sdp

I'm trying to execute the sdm.devices.commands.CameraLiveStream.GenerateWebRtcStream command on a Nest Battery Cam which only support WebRTC streams. The request should be as follows:

```
POST /enterprises/$project-id/devices/$device-id:executeCommand
{
  "command" : "sdm.devices.commands.CameraLiveStream.GenerateWebRtcStream",
  "params" : {
    "offerSdp" : "$offerSdp"
  }
}
```

According to another answered question the following code generates a correct SDP offer which is accepted by Google:

```
const myPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection

myPeerConnection.createDataChannel("dataSendChannel");

myPeerConnection.createOffer({offerToReceiveAudio:!0,offerToReceiveVideo:!0}).then(function(offer) {
    return myPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log(myPeerConnection.localDescription.sdp + "\n");
  })
  .catch(function(reason) {
    console.log("An error occurred, so handle the failure to connect");
  });
```

Has anyone an idea how to "generate" from the last code the $offerSdp to be inserted in the first code?

Answer (score 1):

I have used [this online tool](https://playcode.io/new/) and got the offer in the console.

The following offer was generated:

```
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:124 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000
a=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:126 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:127 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:98 rtx/90000
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:3270553860 cname:{6d4a9509-da38-4be5-b6c0-e1b61b24de50}
m=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=sendrecv
a=ice-pwd:df7be166f74ae8480f36d9b634908922
a=ice-ufrag:da4e0cc3
a=mid:2
a=setup:actpass
a=sctp-port:5000
a=max-message-size:1073741823
```