# Generate OfferSdp For Nest Battery Camera Version

Tags: python, curl, nest, nest-api, nest-device-access

Does anyone know how to generate a valid "OfferSdp"?

It is not in the documentation below:

https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-live-stream#generatewebrtcstream

The only sample code response I saw was here but this is rly not straightforward and I was hoping for a simple CURL command, like all the other nest requests.

[SDP Offer WebRTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70360191/sdp-offer-webrtc)

"OfferSDP" is a long string variable that NEST needs to intake to get an "AnswerSDP".

Ideally curl command wrapped into small python script.

Comment: If it's helpful, I was able to do the demo to completion that google/nest lists here: https://device-access-sample.web.app/ , but now I want to run curl commands from scratch on my end and don't know how to generate the "OfferSDP"

Answer (score 1):

A valid offer is at the link you specified. If you read down further it's in a n expandable toggle:

https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-live-stream#expandable-1

The string is very long which is why it's not in the example itself.